# python 3.7 - how to detect console window closed by the X button?

Tags: python, window

I've been Googling for the past few hour and couldn't find a way to catch a signal or event when my python console app is closed by the X-button on the upper-right corner of the app window.

Using python 3.7,

Any thoughts?

Thanks.